# rsa ssh public key fails ubuntu 12.04 desktop edition, works when logged into GUI

Tags: ssh

I first say, thanks for your time, this may be a known issue but I couldn't find it the answer.

How to replicate:

- copy your public SSH RSA key to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
- reboot ubuntu 12.04 desktop edition
- try to ssh (it will prompt for password)

How to fix:

- Go to the server and log into unity.
- Now ssh public key auth works fine.

Alternate fix:

- SSH the server
- SSH it again, now public key auth will work fine.

This behavior is unusual (I'm a linux admin) hopefully someone knows a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you probably used ecryptfs to encrypt your home directory. It's the "Encrypt your home directory?" option during the installation.

With this option enabled, your home directory (including .ssh/authorized_keys) can't be read until you've logged in once (either into Unity or via SSH with a password). This triggers the ecryptfs to be decrypted and mounted, making authorized_keys readable again.

Workaround:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssh/+bug/362427/comments/12

Comment: Excellent, that makes total sense now. This box is actually a netbook that I converted to be a low-power server, I must have enabled encryption during install because I thought the device would be mobile. The workaround is verified, works fine now, thanks so much!